# How can I include / exclude a part of an included PHP file based on the file I am including it in?

Tags: php, function, include

The title is a bit convoluted. Let me explain better.

I'm making a blog where registered users can delete and edit their posts. The posts are displayed on 2 sites - the main page, and an admin control panel page. The code for generating the posts is in a separate file.

On the title page, everyone should only be able to see the posts. On the admin page, registered users can edit / delete their posts using the same included php file. There is one function smack in the middle of the code that determines if the editing buttons are visible. I want that function to be present when the file is included on the admin page, and not be present when it is included on the main page.

Let's say that the file which is included, blogposts.php looks something like this:

```
<?php

code

function();

rest of code

?>
```

What can i do to exclude that function in the instance where I don't need it?

I've also tried deleting the function and writing:

```
<?php

require "blogposts.php";
function();
?>
```

That executes it only on the last post, but should execute it on all of them since it is part of a while loop in the original code.

So, other than writing the code twice, once with and once without the function, if you guys have any ideas I'd appreciate it,

Comment: Simpley move it to another file, and only require that file when you need it.

Comment: an if statement could be enough, it largely depends on the condition though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place the function inside an if statement, and check the current page against $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

Something like:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/current_page_uri.php')
{
    function();
}
```

And then replace the '/current_page_uri.php' with the URI for your admin page.

Comment: This looks promising! I will try it out and get back to you asap.

Comment: That will be ok, a long as he got a limited number of pages. When the website / application will scale, that can be a very long list of IF's. Simply separating the function to another file and require the file only in the needed places will be much more efficient.

Comment: That's true. But if it's only used in 1 or 2 pages i see no problem.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much! There are only 2 instances where this needs to be used, so there should be no problems with clutter.